# ¿Cómo abrir archivos con formato .psql? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

Me están enviando un archivo con formato .psql y pesa unos 30MB, me dicen que es la base de datos en PostgreSQL, pero con sinceridad no consigo como conectarme para ver los datos de la BD. Agradezco de antemano sus respuestas!

Comment: Probablemente lo que te están enviando sea el `export` de una BD. Si es así entonces lo que tenes que hacer es crear una una `DB` en tu servidor local e importar dicho archivo. Por ejemplo, desde la línea de comandos: `$ psql -U username dbname < dbexport.psql`. Avisanos si esto te sirvio o no.

Comment: Hola Marcos, muchas gracias por tu respuesta, no me sirvió me da una serie de errores como ERROR: relation "public.auth_department" does not exist y muchos otros más, el último error que me salió de ese log fue role "root" does not exist, será que debo crear un usuario root? Soy un poco nuevo con postgres :(

Comment: Ya lo he resuleto, me sirvió tu comando Marcos, muchas gracias! Lo tuve que correr dos veces, la primera vez creó las tablas, luego si insertó los registros. Además creé el usuario root con privilegios completos a esa BD. Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Según lo conversado en los comentarios*)

Lo que te están enviando es el `export` de una `BD` y lo que tenes que hacer es crear una `DB` en tu servidor local e importar dicho archivo.

Por ejemplo, desde la línea de comandos:

```
$ psql -U username dbname < dbexport.psql
```